# Gem::InstallError: celluloid requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, gitlab

I'm trying to install GitLab CI and I got this error.

```
Gem::InstallError: celluloid requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.
An error occurred while installing celluloid (0.12.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install celluloid -v '0.12.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

However, I think my ruby is up to date.

```
# ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [i686-linux]

# ls -l /usr/bin/ruby
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Jan 26 11:20 /usr/bin/ruby -> /etc/alternatives/ruby

# ls -l /etc/alternatives/ruby 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Jan 26 12:17 /etc/alternatives/ruby -> /usr/bin/ruby1.9.3

# rvm list
rvm rubies
=* ruby-1.9.3-p286 [ i686 ]

# which bundle
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286@global/bin/bundle

# which gem
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/gem
```

Any idea what's wrong with me here..?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, your `bundler` or `gem` CLI tools are tied to an installation of Ruby 1.8.

Take a look at `which bundle` and `which gem`; and inspect those files - they are built pointing to a particular ruby installation by default.

(You probably need to install bundler for your current ruby version)

Comment: Ack, I'm not sure at all, then :(

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem too. I use rbenv.

Here is my solution.

1. Make sure your Ruby is loaded by rbenv
2. `$ gem install bundler`
3. `$ rbev rehash`

Now your `gem` should not pointed to your system Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

If you use debian-based linux, try `sudo update-alternatives --config ruby` and `sudo update-alternatives --config gem`. Helped me.